# NGX Uploader upload progress jumping to 100%

Tags: angular, laravel, typescript, amazon-s3, ngx-uploader

When changing the `UploadInput` url to something other than the demo url, the progress bar for the file uploading is near instant, even if the file is still in an uploading state. I've tested with 90mb files at the progress bar will jump from 13% - 60% - 100%. When uploading against the `ngx-upload.com` url it shows the correct progress including an ETA and Upload Speed.

The done event for `UploadOutput` fires correctly after the file has officially uploaded.

I'm using laravels built in storage support to upload s3 files.

```js
onUploadOutput(output: UploadOutput): void {
    console.log('output type: ',output.type)
    switch (output.type) {
      case 'allAddedToQueue':
          console.log('addedAddedToQueue');
          let token = this.userService.currentUser().api_token;
          const event: UploadInput = {
            type: 'uploadAll',
            url: environment.serverUrl + 'api/file-upload',
            // url: 'https://ngx-uploader.com/upload', // <---- this works perfectly
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            },
            includeWebKitFormBoundary: true, // <----  set WebKitFormBoundary
            data: { foo: 'bar' },
            file: this.files[this.files.length - 1]
          };
          this.uploadInput.emit(event);

        break;

      case 'uploading':
        console.log('uploading')
        console.log(output)
        if (typeof output.file !== 'undefined') {
          // update current data in files array for uploading file
          const index = this.files.findIndex((file) => typeof output.file !== 'undefined' && file.id === output.file.id);
          this.files[index] = output.file;
          console.group();
              console.log('progress is: ',output.file.progress.data.percentage)
              console.log('upload speed: ',output.file.progress.data.speedHuman)
          console.groupEnd();
        }
        break;

      case 'done':
            console.log('done');
            this.files.forEach(file => {
                console.log(file.response);
                // Check the file.response.status.
                // If success, grab the file (file.response.file)
                // this.response.emit(file.response);
                console.log(file.response.file)
            });
        // The file is downloaded
        break;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace Facet\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use \LaravelDoctrine\ORM\Facades\EntityManager;
use \Facet\Services\BaseService;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class FileUploadController extends ApiController {

    public function store(Request $request) {
        if($request->hasFile('file')) {
            //get filename with extension
            $filenamewithextension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();

            //get filename without extension
            $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

            //get file extension
            $extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();

            //filename to store
            $filenametostore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

            //Upload File to s3
            $output = Storage::disk('s3')->put($filenametostore, fopen($request->file('file'), 'r+'), 'public');

            $url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename);
            $response = array('status' => 'success', 'file' => $url);
        } else {
            // File could be too large. Depends on what's specified in php.ini
            $response = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error with finding file.');
        }
        return response()->json($response);
    }

}
?>
```

Example of file upload progress data for 93mb file

```
console.log(output)
    /*
        progress: {
            data: {
                endTime: null
                eta: 0
                etaHuman: "00:00:00"
                percentage: 100
                speed: 88097403
                speedHuman: "84.02 MB/s"
                startTime: 1541465378108
            }
        }
    */

console.group();
    console.log('progress is: ',output.file.progress.data.percentage)
    console.log('upload speed: ',output.file.progress.data.speedHuman)
console.groupEnd();

    // progress is:  52
    // upload speed:  80.45 MB/s
```

I'm unsure on what could be the cause for such odd progress behaviour. In the network tab is still shows the pending state and once the response comes through, only then does it the `done` event fire. As it should.

[Demo API url code](https://github.com/bleenco/ngx-uploader/blob/master/src/api/index.ts)

[The issue has been raised before on the git project with no resolve.](https://github.com/bleenco/ngx-uploader/issues/364)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when developing locally. As soon as I uploaded it shot up to 100%. I'm assuming since its all running local (on hard-drive) the file hits the local endpoint instantly. But when I deployed my app to the cloud and tested the progress bar was working fine just like in the demo.